# Why am I receiving this TensorFlow Error?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

> `TypeError: pandas_input_fn should not be called without pandas installed`

```py
input_func = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(x=X_train,y=y_train,batch_size=10,
                                                           num_epochs=1000,shuffle=True)
```

I have pandas installed in my environment, as I've already used it in the same jupyter notebook. I tried installing and uninstall multiple versions of TensorFlow and of Pandas.

Does anybody know what is causing this?

Comment: Did you import pandas?

Comment: yes, Logan. I imported pandas in the first line, and have used it without any issues previous to the line in my question.

Comment: That's weird. I found the context for that error and it occurs when tensorflow tries import pandas as pd and it fails. However, the error actually doesn't show up in the same file in the current master branch of tensorflow, so does that exact error still occur when using the latest tensorflow version?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. I think I've tried just about every combination of TensorFlow and Pandas together and received the same error. I was surprised to not see much on this topic anywhere, so it must be something local to my system..

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what was going on. There was an issue with my pc not having Python installed to the right PATH. Tensorflow was using an older verison of Python3, and that was causing Tensorflow to misinterpret which modules were installed in the virtual environment.

The solution was to uninstall Python and anaconda, re-install anaconda, and then create a new environment within anaconda that houses everything. Then it was aatter of making sure that environment had everything necessary and was using correct Python version.

Comment: Sounds about right. It seems like this issue could potentially affect lots of people, so I'm glad you figured it out.